# How to deploy updates in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, iis-5

Hi 
I have developed the asp.net mvc 2 application. I have deployed it successfully on XP machine that having the IIS 5.1 . it is running fine. but I have updated some changes in my application on development  machine . I want to deploy only these updates over the deployment machine that is XP machine. means only want to update existing deployed application . what procedure I have to be follow ? which files I need to be changes or replaces ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are updating. If you change only the views, css, javascript, you could `xcopy` only the modified files but if you change the source code you need to recompile the application and redeploy it.

Comment: To add to this answer, if you change your source code you only need to xcopy your particular dll. No need to redeploy whole application unless you didn't split your application in multiple logical layers.